# CSS-animated background-color needs too much performance! Looking for options

Tags: css, performance, animation

i have this intro-section on my website with an background-color-animation via CSS-animate. The problem: It needs a lot of performance, my macbook pro is getting hot like fire if i stay for more than 20 seconds on the frontpage.

http://www.timrodenbroeker.de

Do you have a good idea, how i can get the same effect without needing the whole performance of the visitors device? Maybe with Javascript?

THX alot!

```
.intro {
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-color: #ff5326;}
    25%{background-color: #009350;}
    50%{background-color: #2b48c0;}
    75%{background-color: #009350;}
    100%{background-color: #ff5326;}    
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-color: #ff5326;}
    25%{background-color: #009350;}
    50%{background-color: #2b48c0;}
    75%{background-color: #009350;}
    100%{background-color: #ff5326;}    
}

@keyframes AnimationName { 
    0%{background-color: #ff5326;}
    25%{background-color: #009350;}
    50%{background-color: f2b48c0;}
    75%{background-color: #009350;}
    100%{background-color: #ff5326;}    
}
```

Comment: Not sure how switching to JS would achieve any difference. The GPU is still gonna be working pretty hard whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is that you're an infinite-loop. The CPU will therefore get hot. A property you can add to `.intro` is

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

This piece of code should lower the performance needed. See http://ariya.blogspot.se/2011/07/fluid-animation-with-accelerated.html

Switching to Javascript should make any differ, so I would go with the property mentioned above. If you don't want that I guess using gifs is an option, but it's not very elegant.

Hope this helps